# Angular js display name based on selected item and url path

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am starting out on the angular seed.  I have a json file that displays items like the below.

```
{
    "id":"1",
    "name":"Spain",
    "abbrev":"esp"
}
```

When I click on a country in the list I want to the display the details such as the name for this item.

I have this working as shown below.

```
    /* app.js */
    'use strict';

    // Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
    angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','myApp.controllers','myApp.services'])

    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/view1.html',
        controller: 'CountryCtrl'
      });
    }])

    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when('/:name', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/view2.html',
        controller: 'CountryCtrl'
      });
    }])

    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
    }]);

    /* services.js */
    angular.module('myApp.services', [])
    .factory('Countries', ['$http', function($http) {
        var Countries = {};
        Countries.name = '';
        Countries.listCountries = function () {
            return $http.get('../api/countries');
        },
        Countries.ChangeName = function (value) {
            Countries.name = value;
        }
        return Countries;
    }]);

    /* controllers.js */

    angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])

    .controller('CountryCtrl', ['$scope', 'Countries', '$location', function($scope, Countries,$location) {
        listCountries();
        function listCountries() {Countries.listCountries()
          .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
              $scope.countries     = data.countries;
          })
          .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              $scope.status = 'Unable to load data: ' + error.message;
          });
        }
        $scope.name = Countries.name;
        $scope.changeView = function(countryName,indx){
            $location.path(countryName);
            $scope.name = Countries.ChangeName(countryName);
        }
    }]);

    /* templates/view1.html */
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="country in countries">
        <div ng-click="changeView(country.name,$index)">{{country.name}}</div>
      </li>
    </ul>

    /* templates/view2.html */
    {{name}}
```

What I can't get to work is that if I go to http://www.example.com/app/#/ then navigate to spain in the list then I get taken to http://www.example.com/app/#/esp and {{name}} gets outputted as esp.

However if I navigate straight to http://www.example.com/app/#/esp without first clicking on spain in the list I get no value in my $scope.name

How can I achieve this?
I want the name to also be set based on the location path if it is available.
I know that $location.$$path will get me /esp however I don't really think this is the best idea to use this incase the url builds out to something bigger eg http://www.example.com/app/#/esp/events

can I some how access the index or id of the item so that I can then access the data like

```
    {{countries[0].name}}
```

where 0 is id of esp - 1.
What is the best approach?

Comment: I don't really understand what your service is supposed to do...

Comment: Also, you have some errors in your js code. `$scope.status = 'Unable to load data: ' + error.message;`--> Error is not defined. Theres an extra comma between `Countries.listCountries` and the next function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mate, there are a couple of issues with your app.

- Your service retains "state" although is only used to retrieve information
- You're using the same controller to 2 different views (bad practice)
- $scope.status = `'Unable to load data: ' + error.message;` --> Error is not defined
- There are a couple of js errors too, like strayed commas and stuff

Anyways, here's a revised version of your code. [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/1xtc0zhu/)

---

```
// Instantiate your main module
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

// Router config
myApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/view1.html',
        controller: 'CountryListCtrl'
      })
      .when('/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/view2.html',
        controller: 'CountryCtrl'
      })
  }
]);

// Your Factory. Now returns a promise of the data.
myApp.factory('Countries', ['$q',
  function($q) {
    var countriesList = [];

    // perform the ajax call (this is a mock)
    var getCountriesList = function() {
      // Mock return json
      var contriesListMock = [{
        "id": "0",
        "name": "Portugal",
        "abbrev": "pt"
      }, {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Spain",
        "abbrev": "esp"
      }, {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Andora",
        "abbrev": "an"
      }];
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      if (countriesList.length == 0) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          deferred.resolve(contriesListMock, 200, '');
          countriesList = contriesListMock;
        }, 1000);
      } else {
        deferred.resolve(countriesList, 200, '');
      }
      return deferred.promise;
    }

    var getCountry = function(id) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      if (countriesList.length == 0) {
        getCountriesList().then(
          function() {
            deferred.resolve(countriesList[id], 200, '');
          },
          function() {
            deferred.reject('failed to load countries', 400, '');
          }
        );
      } else {
        deferred.resolve(countriesList[id], 200, '');
      }
      return deferred.promise;
    }

    return {
      getList: getCountriesList,
      getCountry: getCountry
    };
  }
]);


//Controller of home page (pretty straightforward)
myApp.controller('CountryListCtrl', ['$scope', 'Countries',
  function($scope, Countries) {
    $scope.title = 'Countries List';
    $scope.countries = [];
    $scope.status = '';

    Countries.getList().then(
      function(data, status, headers) { //success
        $scope.countries = data;
      },
      function(data, status, headers) { //error
        $scope.status = 'Unable to load data:';
      }
    );
  }
]);

// controller of Country page
// Notice how we use $routeParams to grab the "id" of our country from the URL
// And use our service to look for the actual country by its ID.
myApp.controller('CountryCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'Countries',
  function($scope, $routeParams, Countries) {
    $scope.country = {
      id: '',
      name: '',
      abbrev: ''
    };
    var id = $routeParams.id;

    Countries.getCountry(id).then(
      function(data, status, hd) {
        console.log(data);
        $scope.country = data;
      },
      function(data, status, hd) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    );
  }
]);
```

Comment: thanks for the great explanation!  Do you happen to have a link to it in a fiddle or something?  When I run it on localhost I am getting Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module templates/view1.html due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'templates/view1.html' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: I have checked the spelling, I am not sure that is the issue, I am loading my scripts in this order, angular,angular-route,app.js,services.js,controllers.js
and have also tried swapping services and controllers, with the same result?  Do you have any ideas here?

Comment: yeah, I'm sorry. My bad. Check my edited answer. 

This line is at fault. `var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'templates/view1.html', 'templates/view2.html']);`. Remove the templates here.

Comment: I had read that the method you used to instantiate the module was  better than what I had.. thanks again there have been some great tips in this answer.

Answer (score -2):

In your "CountryCtrl", if you include $routeParams and use $routeParams.tlaname, you will have access to the tlaname. You can then use that to initialize your data.